# (ruby on rails) page.call not invoking javascript when data has international characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby and am picking up on a rails project and am seeing something wierd.

I have a controller action that is not invoking the javascript function when page.call is used, but it only does this when the argument data includes international characters.  If I fix the data, it works as expected.

Here's what I'm doing in ruby:

```
class MyProblemController < ApplicationController

    def view
        arg1 = ["This", "is", "fine"]
        arg2 = ["Data", "datum", "datums"]
        arg3 = ["Good", "Bäd", "Ũgly"]

        render :update do|page|
          page.call("myJavascriptFunction", arg1, arg2, arg3)
        end
    end
```

On the web page, I can set a breakpoint in "myJavascriptFunction" and it NEVER gets called.  If I remove the characters with the diacritical marks, it works just fine.

As a ruby n00b, this is perplexing.  What's going on here? How can I make this support international characters?

I did try the magic comment "# encoding: UTF-8" at the top of my controller.rb file and it doesn't make a difference, in case it's supposed to.

Thanks!

Edit:  App is using rails 2.3.2 & I can't change it.  Is using 1.6.0.3 of prototype.js

Comment: you are using jquery or prototype and which version of rails?

Comment: It's using prototype.  I'm a n00b and not exactly sure if these are the right versions. The ruby interpreter is 1.8.7.  In RubyMine 4.5, in the Project Settings "Ruby SDK & Gems" section, it shows activerecord, actionpack, etc is 3.1.0.  Arel is 2.2.1.   

Even though it says activerecord is 3.1.1, my models don't seem to want to support scopes, if that means something.

Comment: by default rails 3.1 onwards default library is jquery is there any specific reason to use prototype?

Comment: the reason it's using prototype is because the guy who wrote it chose to use prototype.  Couldn't tell you why really.

Why would jquery vs. prototype make a difference in regards to invoking a javascript func on the page via an ajax call? 
Isn't this a rails mechanism? I would imagine(but I don't know) that rails doesn't care....

Comment: checkout gem file if present or environment.rb or application.rb you can identify rails version might be it's older app that's why prototype is used

Answer (score 0):

You can try `page.call << "myJavascriptFunction(#{arg1},#{arg2},#{arg3})"` more info you can found [here](http://tempe.st/2007/08/rails-and-javascript-pagecall-gotchas/).

Comment: I did try this, to w/ no luck:

def myaction
      page << "showFilter(#{jArrayParam(arg1)}, #{jArrayParam(arg2)}, #{jArrayParam(arg3)})"
    end
  end
  
  private

  def jArrayParam(array)
    return "'" + array.map{|i| "\"" + i + "\""}.join(",") + "'"
  end